# P.Lax's textbook functional analysis: Chap 4.2 Banach limit, Theorem 3.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> P.Lax's textbook functional analysis: Chap 4.2 Banach limit, [Theorem 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=18VqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA32). I am confused about the proof of (iv): the generalized limit LIM $a_n$, so that 
>   $$\liminf a_n \leq LIM a_n\leq \limsup a_n.$$

The textbook claims that the expression $p((a_n))=\limsup a_n$ applied to $l((a_n))$ and $l(-(a_n))$ where is the linear functional of convergent sequence(classical limit):
$$-p(-(a_n))\leq l((a_n))\leq p((a_n))$$

> My question: By the Hahn-Banach theorem, do we get the $LIM (x)\leq p(x)$? Then we have 
>   $$LIM((a_n))\leq \limsup a_n$$
>   So
>   $$LIM(-(a_n))\leq \limsup -a_n=-\liminf a_n$$
>   So 
>   $$-LIM(-(a_n))\geq \liminf a_n$$?

Is it right?

I do not why Yiorgos S. Smyrlis does this way?
[Banach Limit: understanding this step in the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787365/banach-limit-understanding-this-step-in-the-proof)

Comment: Yes, what you have done is right. Finally $-LIM (-(a_n))=LIM (A_n)$ by linearity.

Comment: @KaboMurphy So if we assume $LIM(a_n)\leq p(x)$ we can do as my way. But why we can also assume $\Vert LIM \Vert =1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get $LIM(x)\le p(x)$ is as follows:

$LIM$ is a linear functional with norm $1,$ such that if $x=(x_n)_n$ is convergent then $LIM(x)=\lim_n x_n.$

Let $x'=(x'_n)_n$ where $x'_n=\|x\|+x_n,$ so $x'_n\ge 0$ for all $n.$

For any $r>0$ define $y(r)=(y_n(r))_n$ and $x''(r)=(x''_n(r))_n$ by letting $y_n(r)=x'_n$ and $x''_n(r)=0$ if $x'_n\ge \|x\|+p(x)+r;$ while letting $y_n(r)=0$ and $x''_n(r)=x'_n$ if $x'_n<\|x\|+p(x)+r.$

Now $x'=y(r)+x''(r),$ but $\{n:y_n(r)\ne 0\}$ is finite, so $LIM(y(r))=0.$ So $$\|x\|+LIM(x)=LIM(x')=LIM(y(r)+x''(r))=LIM(x''(r))\le$$ $$\le \|x''(r)\|\le \|x\|+p(x)+r.$$ The last inequality comes from $\forall n\;(\,0\le x''_n<\|x\|+p(x)+r\,).$

Hence $LIM(x)\le p(x)+r$ for all $r>0,$ so $LIM(x)\le p(x).$

Comment: In case it isn't "obvious", $\{n:y_n(r)\ne 0\}=\{n: x_n\ge r+\lim \sup x_n\},$ which is finite if $r>0.$

Comment: So is my way right?

Comment: Regarding the lim sup & lim inf, YES.

Comment: So why the norm of LIM is 1?

Comment: I don't know what Lax's definition of $LIM$ is. My 2nd line is usually part of the definition. E.g let $C$ be the vector subspace of  sequences with Cesaro means, and let $LIM(x)$ be the Cesaro mean of $x$ for $x\in C.$ Then $\sup \{|LIM(x)|/\|x\|: 0\ne x\in C\}=1.$ By the Hahn-Banach Theorem extend the domain of $LIM$ to  the whole  space, keeping the norm $1$. (The extension is not unique). In this way, if $z_n=x_{n+1}$ for all $n$ then $ LIM(z)=LIM(x)$ because the Cesaro mean of $z-x$ is $0$.